# how to send message Bluetooth device swift?

Tags: swift, bluetooth

How can i write to bluetooth device. I am getting the following errors.

> Optional(Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=3 "Writing is not
>   permitted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Writing is not
>   permitted.})
>
> Optional(Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=13 "The value's length is
>   invalid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The value's length is
>   invalid.})

```
 func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        if let characteristics = service.characteristics {
            for char in characteristics {
                str.append("10,")         str.append("323232323323232")
                var message = #"32,48,89,"#
                str.append(message)
                var sks = String()
                sks = str.toString()
                print(sks.byteArray)
                peripheral.writeValue(sks.byteArray.data(using: .utf8), for: char, type: .withResponse)
            }
        }
    }
extension String {
    var byteArray : [UInt8] {
        return Array(utf8)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question and provide more information about the problem. At the moment, it's insufficient to provide help. Add your code. Describe the GATT services and characteristics. Describe which devices has which Bluetooth role (central manager, slave). Add the appropriate tag for the operating system.

Comment: You need to show us the code that you currently have. As @Codo mentions in the above comment.

Comment: Please don't add code in comments (or answers), [edit] your question instead. Code in comments is unreadable. (But make sure you format it in your question by indenting 4 spaces.) Please also read [ask].

Comment: @alexis Please take the time to format the code such that it's readable. There is an easy to use button (`{}`) for it.

Answer (score 1):

I see three potential problems in your code:

1. You are writing to all characteristics of the service. However, a GATT service has several characteristics (some are just a description of other characteristics). Not all of them are writeable. Therefore, check for the relevant characteristic UUID and only write data to it.
2. You are writing to all services of the peripheral. However, the peripheral likely has many services, e.g. it usually includes a service providing the full device and manufacturer name. Therefore, check for the relevant service UUID and only continue processing for it.
3. The data you want to send it quite long. Bluetooth devices can be limited to only 23 bytes of payload per message. The effective maximum length is negotiated when the connection is established. Use [CBPeripheral.maximumWriteValueLength(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1620312-maximumwritevaluelength) to check for the maximum length and send the data in several chunks. If you have to split your message into several chunks, you have to wait for the [peripheral(_:didWriteValueFor:error:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518823-peripheral) callback after each chunk.

**Update**

It might not be needed to wait for callback.